# Can't compile C program using MariaDB on CentOS

Tags: mysql, c, centos, mariadb, mysql-connector

I want to run C programs with a connection to mariaDB, for that I have installed mariaDB version:

```
 Server:            MariaDB
 Server version:        10.1.11-MariaDB MariaDB Server
 Protocol version:  10
 Connection:        Localhost via UNIX socket
 Server characterset:   latin1
 Db     characterset:   latin1
 Client characterset:   utf8
 Conn.  characterset:   utf8
```

But I came through an article

[image]

So, i didn't install C connector (due to similar nature of mysql-mariaDB) and tried this sample program from this link http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/.

But it says:

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# gcc version.c -o version  `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
bash: mysql_config: command not found...
version.c:1:23: fatal error: my_global.h: No such file or directory
#include <my_global.h>
          ^
compilation terminated.
```

Then I tried installing `libmysqlclient-dev/libmariaclient-dev` & it says no package `libmysqlclient-dev/libmariaclient-dev` available.

Now what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out which package provides you with mysql_config. From what I've checked you can do it by `yum whatprovides mysql_config`. In case of Arch I got:

```
[root@main]# pkgfile mysql_config
extra/libmariadbclient
```

Comment: I tried that using yum, I got this message: 
MariaDB-devel-10.1.11-1.el7.centos.x86_64 : MariaDB: a very fast and robust SQL database server
Repo        : mariadb
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/mysql_config,


I added /user/bin to path but same response as earlier.

Comment: So yum found for you package name. You should install it. /usr/bin is searched by default so no need to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing **MariaDB-devel** package from [MariaDB repository](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/yum/).

Answer (score 0):

I my case, the compiler couldn't find `my_global.h`

I tried:

```
$ mysql_config --include
-I/usr/include/mysql
```

But, the file was under `/usr/include/mysql/server/my_global.h`

This worked:

```
gcc [......] `mysql_config --include`/server
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a pretty old thread and this probably has been resolved. However, I was able to make it work after deploying:
yum install mariadb-devel

Answer (score 0):

You should `#include <mysql/mysql.h>` after installing the developer package. You should not include `<my_globals.h>` directly.

You might also be interested in [MySQL Connector/C Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-c/en/) and [23.8 MySQL C API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api.html) in the Oracle docs.

```
$ sudo dnf install mariadb-devel
...
```

And then:

```
$ find /usr/include -name my_global.h
/usr/include/mysql/my_global.h
/usr/include/mysql/server/my_global.h

$ cat /usr/include/mysql/my_global.h
/* Do not edit this file directly, it was auto-generated by cmake */

#warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h>
```

And finally:

```
$ find /usr/include -name mysql.h
/usr/include/mysql/server/mysql.h
/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h
```

---

And a test:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

And:

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c -o test.exe -lmysqlclient
```